# unable to preview lightning component in firefox

Tags: lightning-web-components, firefox

I am searching lightning component on Salesforce Lightning Web Component Library and there has a option to preview the component. But I can't preview the component on Firefox browser but works perfectly fine on other browser.

error:
SecurityError:
The operation is insecure.

Comment: It would help a lot if you stated which component caused this to happen and in which context the preview is being shown (the URL). Please [edit] to add details.

Comment: Can you disable the [Tracking Protection](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdpIAUAZ/firefox-tracking-protection-warning) in firefox and see if it helps?

Comment: thanks @Swetha .....it helps!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is related to Firefox [Tracking Protection](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enhanced-tracking-protection-firefox-beta-android?redirectslug=enhanced-tracking-protection-firefox-preview&redirectlocale=en-US). As confirmed over comments, disabling the Tracking Protection helped fix the error.

Recommend upvoting this related [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdpIAUAZ/firefox-tracking-protection-warning)

You could add some custom code to detect the Tracking Protection in Firefox and if detected, display a warning message to customers.